R: Dynamically Updating the Probabilities of a Pancake Being Flipped
I am working with the R programming language.
I am trying to simulate a "pancake flipping on a frying pan" experiment with the following conditions:

Each turn, there is a 0.5 probability of the pancake being "selected for flipping" (e.g. imagine randomly shaking the pan and hoping the pancake flips)
If the pancake is indeed flipped, there is a 0.5 probability that it lands on heads and a 0.5 probability it lands on tails
At each turn, we record the cumulative number of heads and tails observed - if the pancake is not selected for flipping, the side the pancake is currently on contributes towards the cumulative numbers

Here is my attempt to simulate this pancake flipping experiment :
set.seed(123)

#turns
n <- 100

# selection probabilities 
selected <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)
coin_flip <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)

# base data frame
df <- data.frame(turn_number = 1:n,
                 selected = ifelse(selected == 1, "yes", "no"),
                 current_result = ifelse(selected == 1, ifelse(coin_flip == 1, "heads", "tails"), "not_selected"))

# previous_result column
df$previous_result <- c("not_selected", df$current_result[-n])

# new column for most recent non "not_selected" result
df$most_recent_non_not_selected <- df$current_result
for(i in 2:n) {
  if(df$most_recent_non_not_selected[i] == "not_selected") {
    df$most_recent_non_not_selected[i] <- df$most_recent_non_not_selected[i-1]
  }
}

# set most_recent_non_not_selected to NA when the coin is selected
df$most_recent_non_not_selected[df$selected == "yes"] <- NA

# add new column that merges current_result and most_recent_non_not_selected
df$merged_result <- ifelse(is.na(df$most_recent_non_not_selected), df$current_result, df$most_recent_non_not_selected)

# add new columns for cumulative counts of "heads" and "tails"
df$cumulative_heads <- cumsum(df$merged_result == "heads")
df$cumulative_tails <- cumsum(df$merged_result == "tails")

The result looks like this and seem to be correct (i.e. one of the cumulative count columns is always increasing):
    turn_number selected current_result previous_result most_recent_non_not_selected merged_result cumulative_heads cumulative_tails
             1       no   not_selected    not_selected                 not_selected  not_selected                0                0
             2      yes          tails    not_selected                         <NA>         tails                0                1
             3       no   not_selected           tails                        tails         tails                0                2
             4      yes          heads    not_selected                         <NA>         heads                1                2
             5      yes          tails           heads                         <NA>         tails                1                3

My Question: Now I am trying to add another detail to this simulation to make it a bit more realistic

Imagine that the longer the pancake sits on the pan without being selected, it starts to burn and stick to the pan, becoming much harder to flip. I want to make it so that each turn the pancake is not selected, the probability of it being selected for flipping reduces by 0.01. However if we are able to dislodge it, the counter resets and goes back to 0.5.
Imagine that the side which is cooked more is also heavier. Thus, when the pancake is flipped, its more likely to land on the heavier side as a function of its cumulative ratios. For example, if cumulative_heads=1 and cumulative_tails=3, the pancake is 3 times more likely to land on tails than heads

Can someone please show me how to add these details to my simulation?
Thanks!

The cooked side is lighter as moisture has been driven off, but that's a quibble in the context of 'imagine'. Is the output also meant to signal 'when' the pancake should be flipped?

Let's say the pancake isn't flipped for the first turn.  On the next turn, it is selected to flip. It's cumulative heads count is 1, and it's cumulative tails count is 0. The cumulative ratio is 1/0 = Infinity. The pancake is unflippable. (Well, you can flip it, but it will always land on Heads.) I think you need to change your "ratios" rule to allow for 0s without breaking.

One potential way to resolve that issue would be to give the ratio a bit of "mass" at 50/50, say start the cumulative counts at 10 each.

@gregor thomas: thank you for your reply! I agree with your comments... I am open to modifying this problem to have different constraints and make it easier to solve. Please feel free to do so. Thanks!

I made a function to do this. The only argument is n, the number of turns. Instead of creating the whole data frame first, you need to create just one row and then iterate through each row, updating the probabilities at each iteration. For the extra detail #2, I use odds but you could use other methods, such as Bayes posteriors.
require(dplyr)
set.seed(3210)

pancake_flip <- function(n) {
  # Initialise
  df <- data.frame(turn_number = 1,
                   p.selected=0.5,
                   p.flip=0.5,
                   selected = "no",
                   current_result = "not_selected",
                   cum.heads = 0,
                   cum.tails = 0)
  # Iterate
  for(i in 2:n){
    if(i==2){
      # Initial values
      cum.heads <- 0
      cum.tails <- 0
      previous_result <- "not selected"
      
      # Initial probabilities
      p.selected <- 0.5
      p.flip <- 0.5
      
    } else {
      # Extra detail 1: Update selected probability
      if(current_result=="not_selected") {
        p.selected <- p.selected - 0.01 
        # Check probability - it cannot fall below 0
        if(p.selected<0) stop("The pancake is burnt to a crisp") 
      } else { 
        # Reset initial probabilities
        p.selected <- 0.5
      }

      # Extra detail #2: Adjust flip probabilities based on cumulative sums
      odds <- (1 + cum.heads)/(1 + cum.tails)
      p.flip <- odds/(1 + odds)
    }
    
    # Simulation
    selected <- rbinom(1, 1, p.selected)
    coin_flip <- rbinom(1, 1, p.flip)
    
    selected = ifelse(selected == 1, "yes", "no")
    current_result <- ifelse(selected == "yes", 
                             ifelse(coin_flip == 1, "heads", "tails"), 
                             "not_selected")
    
    # Save the current result if the pancake was flipped
    # If the pancake is not selected for flipping, 
    # the side the pancake is currently on contributes towards the cumulative numbers.
    if(selected=="yes") previous_result <- current_result

    if(current_result=="heads") {
      cum.heads <- cum.heads + 1
    } else if(current_result=="tails") {
      cum.tails <- cum.tails + 1
    } else if(current_result=="not_selected") {
      if(previous_result=="heads") cum.heads <- cum.heads + 1
      if(previous_result=="tails") cum.tails <- cum.tails + 1
    }
    
    # Update data frame
    df <- rbind(df, data.frame(turn_number=i,
                               p.selected=p.selected,
                               p.flip=p.flip,
                               selected=selected,
                               current_result=current_result,
                               cum.heads=cum.heads,
                               cum.tails=cum.tails))
  }
  df
}

Call the function and look at the first and last 5 rows.
df2 <- pancake_flip(n=100)

dplyr::slice(df2, c(1:5, 95:100))

   turn_number p.selected    p.flip selected current_result cum.heads cum.tails
1            1       0.50 0.5000000       no   not_selected         0         0
2            2       0.50 0.5000000       no   not_selected         0         0
3            3       0.49 0.5000000       no   not_selected         0         0
4            4       0.48 0.5000000      yes          heads         1         0
5            5       0.50 0.6666667      yes          heads         2         0
6           95       0.50 0.4731183       no   not_selected        43        49
7           96       0.49 0.4680851       no   not_selected        43        50
8           97       0.48 0.4631579       no   not_selected        43        51
9           98       0.47 0.4583333       no   not_selected        43        52
10          99       0.46 0.4536082       no   not_selected        43        53
11         100       0.45 0.4489796      yes          heads        44        53


@ Edward: thank you so much for your answer! One thing I wanted to ask you please  ... in the final answer, can you please add two columns that record the probabilities at each row? Thank you so much!

Sure. Check the revised answer.

@ Edward: Thank you so much for these updates! Just to clarify, "p.flip" is the probability of getting heads, correct?

Can you please explain this comment, "For the extra detail #2, I use odds"? Thank you so much!

Sure. You said: "...when the pancake is flipped, its more likely to land on the heavier side as a function of its cumulative ratios." Odds is related to likelihood. And the ratio of cumulative sums of two competing events is akin to the odds of one event occurring compared to the other. Finally, the probability of one event occurring is defined as "odds / (1 + odds)".

Yes, p.flip is the probability of "heads", since you had current_result <- ifelse(selected == "yes", ifelse(coin_flip == 1, "heads", "tails"), "not_selected")
